# Use progressbar on login page of windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I Am developing windows phone application with  visual studio 2012 ultimate.
I have one page in my application in which one submit button is present.
I want to use Progress bar when click on submit button  and it will display till next page is loaded.I  already add Progress bar control from toolbox to in my designing file but now but  what to do next?  .So Please anybody  help me....
thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PerformanceProgressBar**

For Windows Phone 7, it is recommended that you use `PerformanceProgressBar` from the [WP Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) due to long standing performance issues with the built-in `ProgressBar`

```
<toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"></toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar>
```

`IsIndeterminate` is used to turn the control on and off. If you set `Visibility` to `Visibility.Collapsed`, the control is still running and using CPU time, which is bad.

**SystemTray + ProgressBar**

Another option introduced in Windows Phone 7.1 (7.5 or Mango), is to add the `ProgressBar` to the `SystemTray`(the built-in native apps use this technique), the following links should be useful...

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/07/creating-a-global-progressindicator-experience-using-the-windows-phone-7-1-sdk-beta-2/

http://blog.duc.as/2011/10/08/using-the-system-tray-to-show-progress-in-windows-phone-7-mango/

http://xamlgeek.net/2012/10/30/using-the-progressindicator-in-the-systemtray-in-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Indeterminate ProgressBar (the one with dots flowing across the screen) then change its Visibility property from Collapsed to Visible when you want to display it. Change it back to Collapsed when you want to hide it.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="playerProgressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="22"  Margin="0"   Visibility="Collapsed" Width="478" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle1}" />
```

If its a normal progress bar then simply set its Value property to the percentage progress you want to show. You can bind the Value property to a member variable in your page.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="playerShowProgress" Height="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding Path=ShowProgressBarValue, Mode=OneWay}" Width="321" Visibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle1}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me and  I want to make Progress bar visible for some amount of time,is there any way to make it possible.If Possible than please  help me.some amount time means in short i want to make some delay to load page so i can see progress bar.